# IVTPA dataset to filter the DATE

Tags: r

I have a data-set,

In the column name IVTPA_DT, I have  `24353, 1/23/09, 09/12/11, 098, 23412, 01/2/2009`... etc. in the rows.
 But I want to filter only the correct format of the date from this rows i.e `12/12/11` & `1/04/2009`.
And I want to ignore those that don't have correct date format and finally apply to the entire data-set.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: its correct, i want to extract all the correct format. the dataset is arranged like m/d/y but some rows has 4567, 099/3445, 23043  etc. so i want to extract only the correct format from the columns and apply to all the columns in the dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need only those 'Dates with the format `%m/%d/%Y(%y`, use `mdy` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
dt1 <- mdy(dt)
dt1
#[1] "2011-12-12 UTC" "2009-01-04 UTC" "2011-09-12 UTC" NA               NA
```

returns all other format as `NA`

If we need to only extract those elements in the original format, use `is.na` to create a logical index

```
dt[!is.na(dt1)]
#[1] "12/12/11"  "1/04/2009" "09/12/11"
```

#### data

```
dt <- c("12/12/11", "1/04/2009", "09/12/11", "24353", "099/3445")
```

Comment: thank you for the aid prof. however, i tried to execute the same same format of the code you sent but it turns all my rows to NAs instead.. here is the sample library(lubridate)
> kar <- mdy(infarct$IVTPA_DT)

Comment: @Karamo I showed a reproducible example, but you didn't show what is going into `mdy`.  It is better to show `dput(head(infarct$IVTPA_DT))`

Comment: > dput(head(infarct$IVTPA_DT))
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "0005-05-24", 
"0006-11-12", "0036-12-02", "0101-02-27", "0102-02-07", "0102-10-22", 
"0215-12-12", "0372-06-10", "1/1/08", "1/1/09", "1/1/10", "1/1/11", 
"1/1/12", "1/1/13", "1/1/14", "1/1/15", "1/10/07", "1/10/08", 
"1/10/12", "1/10/13", "1/10/14", "1/10/15", "1/10/16", "1/11/08", 
"1/11/11", "1/11/12", "1/11/14", "1/11/15", "1/11/16", "1/12/07", 
"1/12/08", "1/12/11", "1/12/12", "1/12/13", "1/12/14", "1/12/15", 
"1/13/07", "1/13/08",,   i want to ignore those of the dates seperated by "-"

Comment: @Karamo The `dput` is not complete, but it seems like you have a `factor` column.  Anyway, it is working fine with me.  There will be a warning when some values are converted to NA as it is not in the standard format.  That is expected

Comment: Thank you  Prof @akrun that works well however, i want to apply the function to all the columns but it returns error due different dimensions.. example kk <- dt1[!is.na(dt1), ] i tried putting ","  before the square bracket but that doesn't work. whats the best way to do it? thanks again

Comment: @Karamo If you want to apply to all columns, use `lapply` i.e. `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {x1 <- mdy(x); x[!is.na(x1)]})`  BTW, I am not a Prof, just an average guy

Comment: hehe, well you are my prof. anythanks lot for the aid. it was really helpful